# trouble installing laravel 4 in cent os 6.5

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel-4, centos

I have done a fresh install of laravel 4 with composer

I have installed apache, mysql, php and all services are running

I tested localhost and it loads correctly.

Problem is when i open localhost/laravel, the  page does load but not all folders are shown (including public folder)

```
Index of /laravel
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[DIR]   Parent Directory        -    
[ ] CONTRIBUTING.md 19-Jan-2014 06:59   145      
[ ] artisan 19-Jan-2014 06:59   2.4K     
[ ] composer.json   19-Jan-2014 06:59   697      
[TXT]   composer.lock   10-Feb-2014 11:12   53K  
[TXT]   phpunit.xml 19-Jan-2014 06:59   566      
[ ] readme.md   19-Jan-2014 06:59   1.8K     
[TXT]   server.php  19-Jan-2014 06:59   519      
[DIR]   vendor/ 10-Feb-2014 11:12   -    
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80
```

and if i open localhost/laravel/public then it throws

```
Forbidden


You don't have permission to access /laravel/public on this server.
```

I dont know what to do. Can someone please help.

Note: i have chmod /var/www/html/laravel/app/storage into 775

I am using fresh install of cent os 6.5

I have done another fresh install with

```
laravel new blog
```

this one seems to work but it also has a problen

when i access localhost/laravel/publc it throws following error

```
ErrorException

    file_put_contents(/var/www/html/blog/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Note: I have already done `"chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/blog/app/storage"`

Comment: Have you ran the `composer install` command?

Comment: I have run composer create-project command

Answer (score 0):

you need to look into the instructions on how to configure your web server for Laravel.

Your virtual root is mapped to `laravel_folder/public` so you don't enter the url as you have above.  The whole site is driven off a single `index.php` file in /public.

You need to configure mod_rewrite as well.

Consult the docs for all this:  http://laravel.com/docs/installation

Comment: my mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: when i access laravel_folder/public then i get forbidden error.

Comment: Please post your apache config.  Your issues seem to have to do with misconfiguration of the webserver

Comment: sry but stackoverflow says my body is longer than allowed so i couldnot paste httpd.conf files. But i have not changed anything in httpd.conf file.and i installed apache through this command "sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install httpd"